# Sitecore ContentSearch LIKE operator fails on non-alpha characters

Tags: c#, linq, sitecore, sitecore7

I am attempting to implement a custom search in Sitecore 7.5 using the ContentSearch.LINQ library and making use of fuzzy search. For strings containing only alpha characters and whitespace, it works like a charm, i.e. "*cxlcium*" will return results for "**calcium**." However, the end goal of this is more to protect against common misspellings - "*St Johns Wort*" should return items with **"St. John's Wort**." Interestingly enough, "St. Johns Wort" will return zero results, and an exact match will throw an exception due to the single quote (I'm assuming that may need to be escaped, though it works without issue on `StartsWith` or `Contains` type searches).  I have tried moving the `minimumSimilarity` value up and down to no avail.

For what it's worth, this is also passing through to a Coveo index rather than Lucene.
Thanks in advance for any insight.

Code is as follows:

```
        var productResults = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
            .Where(x => x["productname"].Like(searchQuery, .7f)
            .Take(10)
            .OrderBy(x => x["productname"])
            .GetResults();
```

Comment: you're missing a `)` after your `Like`, by the way. probably just a copying error to SO

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off using the phonetic match extension provided by Coveo. More info here:

https://developers.coveo.com/display/public/SC201409/Coveo+LINQ+Extensions

Comment: Thanks. This does look promising but I have been finding more and more special snowflake cases; it seems like a synonym dictionary is going to be the best route to attack this.